# What does native code mean in this context of adding an event?

Tags: javascript, events, addeventlistener

I was following a tutorial about adding event listeners, the tutorial gave an example as follows:

```
<button onclick="handleClick()">
```

Then they showed that for this button element in the DOM there is an onclick property which has this function now, I understood that bit ok.

The bit that I didn't understand is, they show another way using addEventListener e.g.

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
});
```

Then they wrote:

```
document.addEventListener
```

they were showing that the event listener now is not attached to the DOM object but the event listener function that was added is "native code" and that it's not possible to see in the function, it's part of the compiler. I found this part confusing, what do they mean it's native code and the native way to add an event listener?

Also what do they mean it's not possible to see this code and that it's part of the compiler?

Thanks for any simple way to explain this idea.

Comment: It just means that, if you were debugging this code, you can't "step inside" the `addEventListener` method, and see the code inside it - as you would be able to for a function or method defined in a library. That's because it's not implemented in JS itself, but is "built into" each javascript engine (and is likely implemented in C or C++). That's what "native code" means here.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Thanks - so what they mean is that "addEventListener" is a built in part of the javascript compiler (the v8 engine) so I can't see it? - whereas if it was a function I wrote or from a library I imported then I could see it?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right